# Geting id of textview in RelativeLayout when clicked

Tags: android, textview, click, onclicklistener, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout with many textview like in this main.xml sample.

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
>  
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv00"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"></TextView>
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/tv01"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv00"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"></TextView> ...

...</RelativeLayout>
```

I want in my activity.java to get access to the id of a textview I click. How to do that?
With onClickListener I can listen on RelativeLayout, but how to do it for a specific textview in that layout. Something with getid()?

**activity.java**

```
   RelativeLayout rv =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
    rv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing like a "onChildClick" listener for RelativeLayout.
You could iterate over your TextViews (using `rv.getChildCount()` and `rv.getChildAt(i)`) and add click listeners to the individual views...however, if your RelativeLayout just contains a list of TextViews you might want to consider using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead (and its `setOnItemClickListener()`).

Comment: then I'll use as much setOnItemClickListener() as there are ListViews? I need 5 columns that has to be clickable and then, when I click on one textview, it need to give me another activity were I'll be able to modify it's content (of that textview). Is that possible?